# Serving PDF file using Ruby on Rails - blank/white pages in the downloaded file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

For the brevity of this question let's assume that I have a properly generated PDF file stored in memory and encoded in Base64 (generated outside of Ruby), such as this one:

```
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
```

My initial attempts (slightly refactored after a bit of googling around) looked like this:

```
send_data Base64.decode64(pdf).force_encoding(Encoding::BINARY), filename: "download.pdf", type: "application/pdf", disposition: "inline"
```

While the same code works for other file types (CSV, Excel spreadsheets) it's binary PDF files that seem to draw a blank (pun intended). Oddly enough when I have a PDF file with several pages, the right amount of pages is included in the file but they're all blank.

I've also tried serving a PDF from the disk (I generated the PDF using LibreOffice):

```
send_file "/path/to/file.pdf", :filename => "download.pdf", :type => "application/pdf"
```

But the result is the same. I'm running out of ideas, so I'd be grateful for any tips.

**Note:** I am not generating the PDF files using Ruby/RoR, so suggestions such as using Prawn are out of place. The files themselves are generated independently and stored as base64. I know for a fact that there isn't a problem with the generation process as the base-encoded PDF I've included above is valid (I've checked it using online decoders and using other programming languages).

Comment: Are you able to get the data inside the PDF while serving it from the disk ? like you mention using : `send_file "/path/to/file.pdf", :filename => "download.pdf", :type => "application/pdf"` OR is there some issue with PDF creation using the encoded data you have ?

Comment: No, serving from the disk does not yield any results. I suspect the problem may lie with the server configuration, rather than the code. I'm setting up a separate virtual machine to troubleshoot.

Comment: Have you registered the Mime::Type for PDF ?

Comment: What middleware are you using? PDF files are very sensitive to added/removed bytes, even changes in the EOL marker...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extensive debugging, I've found that the problem wasn't actually caused by my Rails app or its configuration. To ease the development process, we used Grunt for running and watching tasks, which shipped with its own HTTP server (Grunt was listening on port `9000`, while RoR listened on `3000`).

Deconfiguring the Grunt server by using the default Rails WEBRick server worked. It turns out that Grunt has some kind of problem with passing on the correct `Content-Length` headers, which caused the problem. Since we're only using Grunt for development, this will not affect us in production, so I'm closing the question.

I hope this helps somebody at some point.